# Xcode 5 cannot detect iPod Touch (5th) with iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ipod-touch, xcode5

**Problem:**

Xcode cannot detect the iPod Touch while linked in, where iTunes know its existence.

**Further Study:**

An iPad 3 with iOS 7 can be detected.

**Environment:**

- Xcode 5.0 (5A1413)
- iTunes 11.1 (126) 64-bit
- iPod Touch 5th Generation (MD723ZP/A)
- iOS 7.0 (11A465)

Comment: did you try rebooting your ipod touch? also try restarting xcode and your mac, sometimes the hardware driver went wrong and a reboot would help.